# ember-i18n : TypeError: app[initializerType] is not a function

Tags: ember.js, internationalization

I've been installing `ember-i18n` on a working Ember project. (https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n)

After registering an initializer `app/initializers/i18n.js` :

```
export default {
  name: 'i18n',

  after: 'ember-i18n',

  initialize: function(_, app) {
    app.inject('model', 'i18n', 'service:i18n')
  }
};
```

And relaunching the server, I get this error in the console :

```
app[initializerType] is not a function
```

Do you have any idea ?

Ember version : "ember": "1.11.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an incompatibility between ember 1.11.1 and `ember-i18n`.

Upgrading to 1.13.2 (and ember-data 1.13.4) solved the issue, without any changes to the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format of the Initializer is not correct. As per [this example from the Ember Guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/), there are two important parts. First, the factory must be registered (application.register) and then it must be injected (application.inject).

Ember.Application.initializer({
      name: 'logger',

```
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var logger = {
      log: function(m) {
        console.log(m);
      }
    };

    application.register('logger:main', logger, { instantiate: false });
    application.inject('route', 'logger', 'logger:main');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tested, I get the error message even without registering an initializer, so I do not think that the problem is coming from here

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, is that your entire code for the initializer? Where are you importing Ember?

Comment: I don't think there's a stack trace (or I don't know how to get it). It's the entire code, I've tried importing Ember but it did not help. Maybe it has something to do with my Ember version (1.11.1)

Comment: In the chrome dev tools, you can get it by clicking around on the error message

Comment: I think the problem is with the way the initializer is written. I wish the initializer api wasn't so cryptic